# Как убрать обводку кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

После нажатия на нее в ie, она обводится так как на картинке. Как убрать это? В стилях я указал, что обводку делать не надо, на браузер все равно обводит ее.

[image: ьфпуы]

Comment: Что именно вы указали? outline: none?

Comment: border none

Comment: [Убираем пунктирную рамку вокруг элементов в фокусе](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/css-tricks/dotted-border-focus-elements.html)

Answer (score 1):

Существует такой атрибут как outline в css. Он отвечает за ободку вокруг button/input/textarea/...

```
a.no-outline{
    outline:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это у вас устанавливается фокус на кнопке, чтобы снять его или установить на другой элемент, нужный вам, используйте ниже приведённый JS.
На javascript установить и снять фокус будет так:

```
    document.getElementById("focus_del").focus();
    document.getElementById("focus_del").blur();
```

С помощью установки курсора вы можете указывать после каких действий можно нажать например просто энтер, дабы не тянуться пользователю за мышкой.

Comment: нужно просто вставить скрипт?

Comment: Ну как просто вставить, нужно прописать нужный id элемента, нужно придумать куда перенести курсор, нужно придумать логику при каком действии убирать курсор. Я то вам написал именно саму суть и объяснил из-за чего у вас там есть эта "обводка".

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как и в Хроме с Сафари поставит `outline:none`